# Can't figure out the way to trigger Magic Sys Keys via keyboard debian 9 lxdm 0.53-2 xfce4.12.3

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, magic-sysrq

I use a debian 9 with Magic Sys Keys enabled :

```
sysctl -a | grep sysrq
kernel.sysrq = 1
```

if I trigger in CLI, it works :

```
echo f > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

I have something like :

```
emergency sync trigerred
```

from tty1.

But when I try to do <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print/Syst</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> from tty1, **I switch from tty1 to xorg tty7** with in xorg log :

```
[  1019.608] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  1044.548] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
```

Kernel :

```
$ uname -r
4.9.0-6-amd64
```

I use xfce4 4.12.3

No keyboard shortcut with this combo in xfce4 applications menu -> parameters -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts (translated from my mind French to English)

I tried with a fresh new user and it's the same problem.

I tried with no xfce4 session, just tty1 and lxdm on tty7, I still switch to lxdm tty7 if I type the keyboard shortcut

Any clue ?

**EDIT 20180802**

Same thing with cinnamon DM 3.2.7, if I hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print/Syst</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> from tty1, **I switch from tty1 to xorg tty**

Comment: Did you forget the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> in the key sequence? However I believe the MagicSysReq key sequences don't work from X because of the way X handles the keyboard.

Comment: No, I don't type `ctrl`, just `alt+sys+s` (French keyboard)

Comment: I saw that that's only alt+sys+s that moves tty1 to tty7, alt+sys+f works, but now I can't write buffers to disk when I trigger oom-killer

Comment: From my Debian-unstable system, Alt+Sys+S gives an Emergency Sync message in the syslog, even if I do it from X (the kernel sees keypresses before X does).  It might have something to do with your hardware.  Is this a VM?  Is it a standard keyboard layout, or a minimal layout with a Fn key (or better yet, can you share an image?)  You mentioned it's a French keyboard; are you using (left) Alt, or (right) Alt-Gr?  Does "hold Alt, press Sys, release Sys, press S, release S, release Alt" work?